# Is File.Exists an expensive operation?

Tags: .net, file, io, exists

Re: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

Does anyone know if this is a particularly slow or locking operation which could impact server performance in a large environment?

Comment: Also note that File.Exists() almost never needs to be called. It is usually used to validate a future IO operation, but it can't really do that, because the file's existence may change between the time Exists is called and the time the IO operation is performed. It is usually better just to attempt the operation that is being validated, and see if it works. Obviously, there are many counter-examples of this, and your app may qualify as one of them.

Comment: Another example of IO.File.Exists being used is to see if an image  exists before displaying it, and displaying an alternative if it doesn't.

Comment: I found it expensive if you have a lot of files or directories in a single directory. For example, after about 10,000 files/directories in a single directory, using `File.Exists` for a file/directory in that directory is painfully slow. 10 - 100 times slower than when the directory is empty. And it gets exponentially worse as more files/directories are added. So be aware fo that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Locking no.  Slow, depends on what you're comparing it to.  It's fairly cheap as far as I/O goes, but I/O is generally slow overall compared to other operations.  So, if you must use it, it won't hurt too bad.  However, I'd try not to call it more times than is truly necessary!  :-)

Answer (score 15):

In computing, there is actually no such thing as an "expensive operation", unless you consider what it is expensive in relation to.

For instance, in the real world, would $2.000.000 for an object be expensive? What if it is the price of Bahamas? Would it be expensive then? What about for a carton of milk? Is that expensive?

The thing you need to consider is if `File.Exists` is expensive in terms of the overall operation you intend to do, and whether or not you actually have any alternatives.

If you don't have any alternatives, does it matter if it is expensive or not?

For instance, if you do 1 check if the file exists, and then if it does, you load it in, and spend an hour processing it, then I would assume it would not be considered expensive.

However, if you call it 10 times in a single loop, to figure out if a file exists, and then if it does, just increment a number, then it might be the most expensive single operation you do there.

The only way you can know for sure is to actually measure how long that method call takes, compared to what else you in the same operation.

Answer (score 13):

In year 2016 it doesn't seem to be very expensive and there also seem to be no real difference between `File.Exists` and `PathFileExists` ([Why is File.Exists() much slower when the file does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230169/235671)). The only difference I could measure is that it's faster to check for a non-existing file then an existing one:

(Tested on an SSD)

```
[DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private extern static bool PathFileExists(StringBuilder path);

void Main()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        File.Exists(@"c:\Home\Temp\test_.log");
    }
    sw.Stop();
    sw.Dump("File.Exists = false");

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        File.Exists(@"c:\Home\Temp\test.log");
    }
    sw.Stop();
    sw.Dump("File.Exists = true");

    var sb = new StringBuilder(@"c:\Home\Temp\test_.log");
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        PathFileExists(sb);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    sw.Dump("PathFileExists = false");

    sb = new StringBuilder(@"c:\Home\Temp\test.log");
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        PathFileExists(sb);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    sw.Dump("PathFileExists = true");

}
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Ispired by this, I wrote more benchmarks on https://github.com/sntcz/FileExistsBenchmark

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it is (file operations are heavily optimized and cached on most OS's) and most of the other operations are more likely to be culprits here (sockets, DB access, general processing, etc). But, as usual, the best way is to actually profile your application and see if it's an hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

`File.Exisits` with kernel32.dll FindFirstFile open handler to the file. If resulting handle is invalid, it return false. If valid it fill data structure with all stuff like LastAccessTime, CreationTime, file size and so on. And then return true. Nothing blocking.

Answer (score 2):

Best would be to run some tests in your environment.  I have an app that can do 10,000+ per second without a hiccup to my systems.  I consider that pretty fast.